# What is the best practice to return a logic error for a function in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to check whether a user has permission to an employee.

```
function hasEmployeePermission($employeeID, $userKey)
{
    $usersID = DB::table('users')->where('key', $userKey)->value('id');

    if($userID != null) {
        $employeeID = DB::table('employees')->where('user_id', $userID)->value('id');

        if($mployeeID != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want the return value to be more expressive like throwing a **exception**. I think throwing an exception in logical error is not a best practice. I want t know how to modify the code to return an error.

Comment: `return "ERROR MESSAGE";`? If you want it to report in error_log, then you could do `error_log("ERROR MESSAGE");` before the return as well. And you could also kill the page instead of do any return. `die("ERROR MESSAGE");`

Comment: `hasEmployeePermission` sounds like a yes/no question so a boolean is probably the most expressive thing you can have this function return. If the wrong arguments are passed, then that's an exception

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That might be dangerous, right? If a coder used if(hasEmployeeAccess()) it will pass the error situation.

Comment: I agree with @apokryfos. On top of that, you could log that someone tried to access another account

Comment: @apokryfos I want to know why it failed. Whether the key is invalid or the user does not have the permission

Comment: Sounds like unsecure to me to give detailed information to the user about an invalid key or permission.

Comment: @AH. Not if you just use `error_log()`, the user would never see that but it would generate an error_log file. And killing the page with a "No Permission" error may be a good idea, so that the page can never be loaded if they don't have permission.

Comment: I don't know about best practices, but if you want, you can create your own [user-defined exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php), then throw them instead of the false.

Comment: @AH. you really should try to give a single responsibility to your functions. What you need seems to imply that your function is trying to do more than one thing

Comment: Functions called `has/is...` should return booleans, and only throw exceptions for invalid arguments, etc. If you want to use a more exception-based model, then break your code down into `doesUserExist` + `doesUserHaveAccess`, and if either return false then throw an exception from the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple error class.

```
Class myError{
     public $error = true;
     public $message = null;
     function __construct($error,$message) {
         $this->error = $error;
         $this->message = $message;
     }
}
```

then you can do something like this,

```
    if($mployeeID != null)
        return new myError(true,"no permission");
    else
        return new myError(false,"has permission");
```

There could be a lot more functionality added to the class, e.g. logging the error somewhere or things like that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why your function failed and in which case, I would recommend using an enum.

Here is an example :

```
abstract class EmployeeErrors
{
    const WrongID = 1;
    const NoPermissions = 2;
    // etc.
}

function hasEmployeePermission($employeeID, $userKey)
{
    $usersID = DB::table('users')->where('key', $userKey)->value('id');

    if($userID != null) {
        $employeeID = DB::table('employees')->where('user_id', $userID)->value('id');

        if($mployeeID != null)
            return 0;
        else
            if ($userKey == null)
               return EmployeeErrors::WrongKey;
            else ...
    }
    return EmployeeErrors::WrongID;
}
```